# nodejs writeStream benchmarks checking understanding

Tags: node.js

I have the following similar code to benchmark a file write and since I'm trying to better understand nodejs, I thought I'd ask for some clarification:

The following two write functions write the same amount of info to a file, only difference is one waits for the buffer to drain while the other doesn't:

```
// write: 5.163s
// Memory usage: {
//   rss: 34356,
//   heapTotal: 34304,
//   heapUsed: 14375.6953125,
//   external: 703.5712890625
// }
(async () => {
  const startMemory = process.memoryUsage();
  console.time("write");
  const fileHandler = await fs.open("out.txt", "w");
  const stream = fileHandler.createWriteStream();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    const overWatermark = stream.write(` ${i} `);
    if (!overWatermark) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => stream.once("drain", resolve));
    }
  }
  await new Promise((resolve) => stream.end(resolve));
  console.timeEnd("write");
  const endMemory = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log("Memory usage:", {
    rss: (endMemory.rss - startMemory.rss) / 1024,
    heapTotal: (endMemory.heapTotal - startMemory.heapTotal) / 1024,
    heapUsed: (endMemory.heapUsed - startMemory.heapUsed) / 1024,
    external: (endMemory.external - startMemory.external) / 1024,
  });
})();
```

And one without draining the buffer:

```
// write: 4.948s
// Memory usage: {
//   rss: 209304,
//   heapTotal: 190816,
//   heapUsed: 163152.8984375,
//   external: 8110.009765625
// }
(async () => {
  const startMemory = process.memoryUsage();
  console.time("write");
  const fileHandler = await fs.open("out.txt", "w");
  const stream = fileHandler.createWriteStream();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    stream.write(` ${i} `);
  }
  await new Promise((resolve) => stream.end(resolve));
  console.timeEnd("write");
  const endMemory = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log("Memory usage:", {
    rss: (endMemory.rss - startMemory.rss) / 1024,
    heapTotal: (endMemory.heapTotal - startMemory.heapTotal) / 1024,
    heapUsed: (endMemory.heapUsed - startMemory.heapUsed) / 1024,
    external: (endMemory.external - startMemory.external) / 1024,
  });
})();
```

Am I correct to assume that the first takes a little longer because it takes the time to drain the buffer first?

I added a small change to the drained buffer version to better understand what's going on:

```
(async () => {
  const startMemory = process.memoryUsage();
  console.time("write");
  const fileHandler = await fs.open("out.txt", "w");
  const stream = fileHandler.createWriteStream();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    const overWatermark = stream.write(` ${i} `);
    if (!overWatermark) {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve) => stream.on("drain", resolve));
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
  await new Promise((resolve) => stream.end(resolve));
  console.timeEnd("write");

  const endMemory = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log("Memory usage:", {
    rss: (endMemory.rss - startMemory.rss) / 1024,
    heapTotal: (endMemory.heapTotal - startMemory.heapTotal) / 1024,
    heapUsed: (endMemory.heapUsed - startMemory.heapUsed) / 1024,
    external: (endMemory.external - startMemory.external) / 1024,
  });
})();
```

Here what happens is it finishes in roughly the same time as before (5.2s) but uses a lot more memory (941996kb) and throws an error:

```
(node:24376) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [WriteStream]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

And my understand as to why is after a certain point, the if statement checking to see if overWatermark is false was always being entered and so setTimeOuts were being created at every interval of the for loop?

Explaining a big increase in memory.

But I'm not understanding what's going on here:

```
const overWatermark = stream.write(` ${i} `);
if (!overWatermark) {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => stream.on("drain", resolve));
  }, 1000);
}
```

Node is adding 1e6 callbacks to the queue of whichever phase deals with the writes (poll phase?). In addition, after 1 second after the watermark is reached, its also adding the setTimeouts for each iteration. The event loop processes the callbacks in whichever phase has the write callbacks and checks the timer phase for any finished timers whenever its queue is empty?

But wont its queue not be empty until all the callbacks from the writes finish? Why is the MaxListenersExceeded warning showing up in the console after 1 second? Why is the event loop checking the timers phase when its current phase is dealing with callbacks from the 1e6 writes?

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: FYI, you call `stream.end()`, that's asynchronous but you don't wait for it to finish so you aren't timing the whole write process.  You could output to the console when you get the `close` event (that's when the file is closed).  So, you're actually not timing any of the physical disk writes in the 2nd version.  Change your timing to end when the file is actually closed and see what the real timing is then.

Comment: Change `stream.end()` to `await new Promise(resolve => stream.end(resolve))` in both scenarios and then your timing will include writing all the content to the file.

Comment: Ah okay got it, that makes sense. I updated the code to reflect the new benchmarks.

Comment: I've added extra for some behavior I'm not understanding, could you take a look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `stream.end()` to `await new Promise(resolve => stream.end(resolve))` to cause it to actually wait for all the writing to finish.

Change `Change stream.on("drain", resolve)` to `stream.once("drain", resolve)` so you don't accumulate listeners that you are done with (to fix the `MaxListenersExceededWarning` issue).

Remove the `setTimeout()` around waiting for the drain because that's causing it to not actually wait.  I have no idea why you added that.  It's messing things up here.  If you were trying to solve some other problem with that `setTimeout()`, then please explain that problem.

Comment: I added it because like I said I'm trying to better understand node and the event loop and the control flow etc. Basically just dumping async code into sync then reading the output to how node executes better. Thanks for the tips though!

Comment: @Mathew - The `setTimeout()` is non-blocking.  So, all it does is register its timer and then immediately return so execution continues.  So, it wasn't "waiting" for the drain when surrounded by the `setTimeout()`.